# passing two values to php page in url via jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this function after an ajax post.

```
success: function(){

    window.location = 'morefive.php?document=' + path;
    }
```

I wanted to know how I could pass two variables, I have been having trouble figuring this out for jquery. It would be the equivalent of `morefive.php?document=path&url=link`
the variable link being a url (would it have to be encoded?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - pass two variables to what?  Pass two variables into the success event handler?  I guess that depends on where you're getting `path` and `link` from.

Comment: im passing two variables to morefive.php......one is path (number) and one is link (string)

Comment: Yes, but where are you getting those values?  You mention you're trying to figure this out with jQuery, but I don't see where jQuery plays a part in this.  Are you trying to get the values passed into the success callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question, you need to use encodeURIComponent() like this:

```
window.location = 'morefive.php?document=' + path + '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(link);
```

Comment: agreed this is a good answer. but check out encodeUIRComponent doc if you can http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: edited with encodeURIComponent because it's better, as you said, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = 'movefive.php?document=' + path + '&url=' + linkvar
```

Nothing says you can't concatenate multiple strings/variables together. Just separate each `var=value` pair with a `&` character.

Comment: is there a limit on how long the string (url) can be ?

Comment: Depends on the web server, but about 4000 characters total is okay.